# ng-repeat filter spans errors, says it's not getting an array to work with

Tags: angularjs

I do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="member in members | filter : query | orderBy : 'lname' as filteredLeden">
```

And then the browser gives me this:

```
angular.js:13424Error: [filter:notarray]
```

Basically this means that 'members' is not an Array.  But I'm absolutely sure that members is an Array.
What am I missing here???

Comment: are you sure `members` is an array?

Comment: Absolutely.  Did a console.log and this is what is given:  
    memebers = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: could you reporduce this issue on plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: The thing is, the array comes from a firebase backend.  And when i first fire the filters, it is possible the array is just a promise, not a array yet.  So i'm doing the filtering way to soon, probably

Comment: At least, some guy on the firebase forum told me

Comment: CLOSED!!!  The 'some guy at the firebase forum' helped me out and solved it.  But hey, thank you Pankaj for helping me too!